# Remove Local Notification created from previous app version

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I need to create a new version of my app, but removing a section where user had the ability to create Local Notification.  `UILocalNotification`

My doubt is that if a user has created an event with repetition, the notification center still launchs alerts.

Could i call `cancelAllLocalNotifications` to be sure that every notifications previously created would be removed ? Is there a better way to obtain that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can call `cancelAllLocalNotifications` to cancel all scheduled notification when you app first launched. Of course you have to determine if your app is first launched.

Comment: In your opinion, every notifications that i've created for a previous version still live in the new version of the App ?

Comment: Interesting. I think it still exists. Because when you schedule your local notification, it's been handed to the OS. So I think even you delete your app, the scheduled notification will still be there. I haven't tested this though.